# jQuery show hide disabling target attribute

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

Hi I have created a share section for my site these social network links are hidden on the document start.

However when I try to click these links when I unhide my share links the links do not navigate anywhere, if I right click and click open in new tab it works.

My code is below or view [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey5kr/6)

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="open">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="share"><a href="#" id="share">Share</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sharenav">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=index.html" target="_blank">FB</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">G+</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js/js.js

```
$('.sharenav').hide();

$('.share').on('click', function () {
    $('.sharenav').slideDown('slow');
});

$('.share').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.sharenav').slideUp('slow');
});
$('.sharenav').on('click', function () {
    $(this).stop();
    return false;
});
$('.sharenav').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).slideUp('slow');;
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ey5kr/1/ is this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links aren't working because you're actually halting the execution of your link with these lines:

```
$('.sharenav').on('click', function () {
    $(this).stop();
    return false;
});
```

This is another solution (filter the click handler to only the `li`, allowing the `a` to execute as expected):

```
$('li.sharenav').on('click', function () {
    $(this).stop();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks that was correct, sorry I did not know this. I would have accepted other answers however your answer had the only working example. will accept answer after timer runs down

Answer (score 2):

What is this code for?

```
$('.sharenav').on('click', function () {
    $(this).stop();
    return false;
});
```

With this in, when you click on a link, it first looks at the fact that you have clicked on .sharenav (the ul container) which runs this event listener.

This event listener is returning false, so therefore no more events are executed (in this case the link being clicked).

Try removing this code block or `return false;` from it.

I have tidied your code, so now there is a timeout on the hover effect. And also the child container still remains where it is when you move away from the parent elements. Hopefully this will help you if it is what you were going for:

http://jsfiddle.net/JjQWL/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sharenav').on('click', function () {
    $(this).stop();
    return false; // this stops the navigation.
});
```